# Application Installation Failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

Após usar pela primeira vez o Android Studio em um celular, não consegui usar o emulador normalmente. Aparece a mensagem abaixo. Alguém me ajuda por favor?

"Installation failed with message Failed to establish session.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application*?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual a versão do Android Studio e o modelo do celular?

1. Certifique-se de que a depuração USB esteja habilitada e que não há nenhum módulo de segurança no telefone que esteja impedindo a instalação, tal como o a verificação de apps por USB.
2. Tente desativar o [Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run)